# How can I use the site-package of python?

Tags: python-2.7, python3

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have got some site-packages for python via pip, but they work for `python2.7`. how can I use these site-packages in `python3.4` IDLE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply when you install the site packages make sure you install them on both python systems. 
For example if you want to install pygame on python 2 and 3:

```
apt-get install python-pygame # for python 2.x
apt-get install python3-pygame # for python 3.x
```

Also remember the command to start the Python 3 interpreter from the terminal is:

```
python3
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.  There is no backwards compatability between versions 2 and 3.

However,  if you have python 2.x actually installed, make your way to its install file and launch IDLE from there.

It will launch the 2.x version.